# Want to show marker on google map using place id

Tags: xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

Is it possible to show marker on google map using place link.

For example, I have a link for place [BAR PSY](https://goo.gl/maps/JXKa2pe93Tn) place link is https://goo.gl/maps/JXKa2pe93Tn.

Is there any way to show marker on this place in google map.

Comment: Can you confirm if you need interactive map? or you just need to show the location?

Comment: I need to show marker on that place. just want to show location pin.